# How to change background color using color picker without click on button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, color-picker

I want to change the background color using colorpicker without a click on changecolor button. What I want is to change the background color as I am selecting RGB in colorpicker.

```js
function changecolor(){
  let color = document.getElementById('colorpicker').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  
}
```

```html
<input id = "colorpicker" type = "color">
  <button onclick = "changecolor();"> change Color </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this.

```js
let colorpicker = document.getElementById('colorpicker');



  setInterval(()=>{
      let color = colorpicker.value;
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }, 200);
```

```html
  <input id = "colorpicker" type = "color" value="#ffffff">
    <button onclick = "changecolor();"> change Color </button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for. I need one more favor from you, How can I change the default black color. I tried to do this ` <input type="color" id="colorpicker" value="5f9ea0">` but didn't work.

Comment: If you are using HEX value for color then add "#" to your value. ex. - it won't work on 5f9ea0 , You have to write #5f9ea0.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `onchange` event on your colorpicker so that your function will get called and then simply change your background color .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function changecolor(el) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = el.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="colorpicker" type="color" onchange="changecolor(this)">
```

Comment: Thanks, it would work for me. but I was looking for an answer like react color works https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/.  please suggest something for this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("colorpicker").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input id = "colorpicker" type = "color">
```